# Show Active Parents with Inactive Childs

Tags: netsuite

I've run this in the past but never gotten anywhere. I can't seem to run this correctly so as the question, I'm after any Active Parents with ANY Inactive or Display in Website is False Childs.

So in theory this is how it would run but, of course, this doesn't :(

```
CASE WHEN {PARENT.ISONLINE} = "TRUE" AND {ISONLINE} = "FALSE" THEN "ACTIVE" ELSE "INACTIVE" END
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CASE WHEN {PARENT.ISONLINE}  AND {ISONLINE}  THEN "ACTIVE" ELSE "INACTIVE" END
```

Comment: Hello, Sorry I've only just seen this now :( but this doesn't work. It's giving me an error - 

 
`Your formula has an error in it. It could resolve to the wrong datatype, use an unknown function, or have a syntax error. Please go back, correct the formula, and re-submit.

Search: Item Search
Formula: CASE WHEN {PARENT.ISONLINE} AND {ISONLINE} THEN "ACTIVE" ELSE "INACTIVE" END
`